# Firebase behavior changing Depending on what built the program

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, teamcity

I'm attempting to implement Firebase in an existing .Net program using Firesharp. Firebase is being used to propagate information that is changed on one machine over to other machines that may have the same information loaded previously.

I'm attempting to have Firebase store the JSON representation of the objects as the value of a particular key.

When I build in VS 2013 and run the program locally then the values appear like so:

[image: Desired behavior]

As you can see in the picture the JSON string that is the value is having all of its special characters escaped and the value of the key "-Kkvvz8vdPqvZWDmNgHf" is a single string. While I realize this probably isn't the intended structure, at this point this structure works best for our implementation due to the way that the subscriptions are working through Firesharp.

The above behavior is what I see when compiling through my dev environment on my local PC, Every night we use TeamCity to compile the program with the previous days changes and when that compiles the code I am receiving completely different behavior in Firebase:

[image: wrong behavior]

The picture essentially shows that Firebase is taking the JSON representation of the object and breaking out its properties as individual nodes in the tree. Because of that the subscription that the program has to Node "288110_280" is receiving multiple updates, one for each property, instead of one update representing the change object that needs to be processed. We have verified that the configuration of TeamCity mimics our development environments and I've done a 1 to 1 check of the dll's that end up in the applications folder at the end of an install and the output of a build done on my dev environment and the dll's match exactly.

So my main questions are,

1. What dictates whether or not Firebase parses the JSON string that it is given?
2. If Firebase does parse the JSON into individual properties, is it possible to subscribe to the parent node in such a way that we would receive one update containing all of the properties together instead of the properties individually?
3. Is there a way to force Firebase to act as outlined in the first screenshot?

**Edit:

I believe the Teamcity inconsistency is a red herring. I was able to install the program as compiled by Teamcity on two separate machines. One yields the first result and one yields the second result. So this new information basically changes the question to how do I ensure consistent behavior across different machines?

Comment: How are you escaping the JSON strings?  What .Net version are you targeting and are all the machines up-to-date with .Net?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925567(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am generating the un-escaped JSON string and have verified that that is what is being passed into Firesharp the escaping is (sometimes) being done once the JSON string is being passed to Firesharp, I am unable to determine whether it is done by Firesharp or Firebase . We are targeting 4.5.1 and we require 4.5.1 to be installed on any PC that runs our program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've parsed through as about as much source code as I can stand without using a debugger.  Here's what I've found:

- The example you have given above is escaping the string double quotes.  It doesn't look like it's escaping anything else.  This causes me to believe that when Firebase gets the string payload it attempts to parse as JSON and throws on the invalid `\` escape token.  Then Firebase stores as a string. If the `"` isn't escaped, Firebase successfully parses as JSON object.
- Tracing through Firesharp leads me to this [String formating code](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/blob/master/FireSharp/RequestManager.cs#L120) that gives me pause. My first suspicions are that `as string` works on one system and not another.  However, without stepping through the debugger on two different machines to follow the formatting, I'll go down the `_config.Serializer.Serialize` path.
- Turns out the `_config.Serializer.Serialize` method eventually uses a TextWriter to build the string.  TextWriter uses the System's [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) (locale) to help determine how a string is built.

The thing that can change from machine to machine is the locale (CultureInfo).  I know that TeamCity spins up the build agents on the System account, which may or may not have the same locale.

I would probably test this theory using the following code:

```
  CultureInfo culture1 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  CultureInfo culture2 = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
  Console.WriteLine("The current culture is {0}", culture1.Name);
  Console.WriteLine("The two CultureInfo objects are equal: {0}",
                    culture1 == culture2);
```

You can send Teamcity messages using the [wire format](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD3/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity). E.g.

```
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[message 'The current culture is {0}' ]", culture2.Name);
```

---

If the CultureInfo is implied, it takes the system culture.  I suspect that either they are different, or they are invariant.  Instead of using the invariant or implied culture, try setting an explicit culture to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Given the behavior I am seeing in the edit of the original question I believe you may be on the right track with the culture idea. I was able to force the behavior by converting the first `{` to a `<` and then reverting it on the client side before attempting to deserialize the value. So it works but not very clean. I'll look more into the culture idea later but for now I think that's the best bet.